# Getting Direct File Links from Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

Is there a way to get "Direct File Links" from Dropbox in android code without using the Dropbox API's?

I searched a lot on this but did not find a solution. Any responses will be appreciated.

Comment: Of course not. Whats wrong with API?

Comment: Thanks Lixas for quick comment.. I need a quick solution as have no time to read/go thru DropBox CoreAPIs.. I wanted to download files from DropBox.. So If I could get the URL, I can simply download those using one of my pre-build functions..
Anyways, how easy it is to download files from DropBoxs APIs?

Comment: @Lixas arent there quota limits for the api???????

Answer (score 9):

1. get the file link for exemple https://www.dropbox.com/s/blablabla/test.pdf
2. replace www by dl
3. add ?dl=1 to the end

result of our example:  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/blablabla/test.pdf?dl=1

Comment: I'm using the same exemple to provide direct download for my friends and its working well.

Comment: Note that Dropbox does not recommend this method.

Answer (score 9):

Get the Dropbox link. Something like:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefg1234567/image.jpg?dl=0
```

Now replace the part after the ? with raw=1

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefg1234567/image.jpg?raw=1
```

Paste in a browser and press Enter. That will redirect you to the actual file link. Something like:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/aBcdEfGHiJ1234567890/file
```

Be careful to always use the raw=1 link though. The dl.dropboxusercontent.com that you are redirected to has a limited shelf life and will expire.

Comment: Note that Dropbox does not recommend using the direct `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` links. Also note that you may run into CORS errors if you are doing any kind of embedding with the `?raw=1` link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chooser: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android. It will present UI to the user to let them choose a file, and then it will give your app a URL you can use to download the file, or just the file content itself.

Comment: Awesome friend ! Looks promising.. I will try to implement and let you know. Thanks

Comment: when I use chooser it not give me any download option. It is always say to download dropbox first. How can I use dropbox chooser without download dropbox in my phone?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to access files stored on Dropbox. You can easily share the file from the dashboard or the desktop app, which yields:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghijklmnop/file.txt?dl=0
```

And the direct download version:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghijklmnop/file.txt?dl=1
```

And the raw DL version:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghijklmnop/file.txt?raw=1
```

But I also discovered a pattern for the raw DL version without the query parameter:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/raw/abcdefghijklmnop/file.txt
```

And I believe the ID remains the same, eg, in this case `abcdefghijklmnop`.

Interestingly (likely do to my ignorance using `wget`), you can also just ask for the file in the terminal with the following URL:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghijklmnop/file.txt
```

And this downloads the file just fine.

In a browser, requesting that URL will trigger the Dropbox in-browser file viewer, which contains the response from the request, which is messy when dealing with file downloading programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Get the share link of the file:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefg1234567/image.jpg?dl=0
```

At the end, replace dl=0 to dl=1:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefg1234567/image.jpg?dl=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the method described in other answers just does not work, and the url pattern is

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/<hash>/filename?dl=0`
->
`https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/<hash>/filename`