# Using Dropbox to stream videos to custom Android app

Tags: android, video, streaming, dropbox

I am working on a android application to view videos on.  Is it possible to store them in Dropbox and stream them to the native video player in Android.  I am aware of the Dropbox api's, but am not certain this is possible.

Thank-you in advance for any answers

Comment: firstly, you need to get the direct link of you file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781766/getting-direct-file-links-from-dropbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK, you can use the [`getTemporaryLink`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#getTemporaryLink-java.lang.String-) method to get a temporary direct link to the file to give to the media player.